# Getting error To run a first flutter project in android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, command-prompt

I installed android and flutter. Emulator is also opening, its good. I did file - settings - languages and framework  flutter SDK path also.
when i try to run a project it shows No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions.

At the same time when i tried to check the flutter doctor it shows the result like this.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.471], locale en-IN)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    X android-studio-dir = /path/to/android/studio
    X Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I don't know where i did the mistake. and tried to uninstalled android studio and reinstalled for more than 3 times.

Comment: Seems like there are no mistake. Just plug in a a android device or start a emulator before flutter run and if its a real device make sure to enable developer options in settings(Do a google search on this).

Comment: Please run this cmd in sequence  1)~/CLOVER/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb kill-server
2)~/CLOVER/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb devices
3)~/CLOVER/Sdk/platform-tools$ sudo adb kill-server
4)~/CLOVER/Sdk/platform-tools$ sudo adb start-server'

Comment: how shall i  run this command sir, In command prompt if i run this it shows '~' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.